# setting up subdomains to a single ECS on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, subdomain, amazon-ecs

This is more like an architectural question; Shopify is using AWS as its cloud infrastructure and I know when a shop named X-Beauty joins Shopify, they get their own subdomain, it would be something like x-beauty.shopify.com and this happens automatically.

I am trying to setup something like that for our stores, so when an store joins they would get their own subdomain that would be served with a NextJs application on an ECS.

How do I architect something like this? how to set subdomains in backend when an store registers in our product?

Comment: That's more about nameserver config. Route53 has the API for that, other providers may have one too, or you can even host your own nameserver if you're feeling adventurous (don't)

Comment: no I'm not feeling adventurous, I need it for production, no adventure here my friend! 
Can you provide me a link to a document or tutorial for configuring nameservers with route 53 with codes?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html